# How to check element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check if element (`#idname`) exists, then alert a message to user before closing current tab (or browser).

Here is my condition:

```
if (document.contains(document.getElementById("#idname"))) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
      // some code here
}
```

The above code works as well, but my problem is that element (`#idname`) isn't exist in the HTML in first and I will append it to my HTML after page loading. Now that condition doesn't work anymore. Is there any solution?

Comment: Define the handler after appending the element.

Comment: @Vohuman What do you mean "handler" exactly?

Comment: You should use `getElementById("idname")` instead of `getElementById("#idname")`, shouldn't you? The `"#idname"` is jQuery syntax.

Comment: you should run your js code after your element has inserted, how is it getting there, something is putting it it in,js maybe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: @saj There *is* jQuery tag in this question.

Comment: @Gothdo My question isn't only about existing, that's about existing of an element which will be created after page-loading. So, don't seem duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check the existence of the element in your `onbeforeunload` handler:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
   if ( document.getElementById("idname") ) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask another question? *(it isn't related to the above question, it is a small question which doesn't has enough worth to I ask it on SO)*

Comment: Thanks *(my Iranian friend)* ..! Well I'm trying to create a small markdown editor *(something like SO's textarea)*, [Here is a small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3g3gf7kq/8/) of that. There is just one button *(named Bold)* which appends two stars `**` around selected/highlighted text.

Comment: Now, what's the problem? That is: **bad-handling-spaces-around-highlighted-text** ..! To solve that problem, I have created a regex to handle spaces as well like this: `$textarea.val( $textarea.val().replace(/\s*(\*+)\s*(.*?)\s*(\*+)\s*/g,' $1$2$3 ') );`

Comment: The above regex should be paste on line 13 of that fiddle and it works as well. But it has a new problme, When I use that regex, the text-highlighting hides after clicking on Bold, Well do you know any workaround to I have both text-highlighting and using that regex?

Comment: The google CDN has been filtered in Iran and the demo isn't run properly for me. Well, let me answer your question tomorrow, It's 5 a.m. and I'm sleepy right now.

Answer (score 2):

just check if you can select it:

```
$("#idname").length > 0
```

or

```
document.getElementById("idname") === null
```

You have to do the request inside your function! (See answer of Vohuman)

Comment: It's just an alternative of the OP's current code, it doesn't provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, @Vohuman is right, `.length` and `=== null` exactly the same with `.contains` ..

Comment: you are right, your answer is what should solve the problem.

Comment: And please remove `#` in this line : `document.getElementById("# ..`